# how to print variable importance of all the models in the leaderboard of h2o.automl in r

Tags: r, h2o, leaderboard, automl

I am using `automl()` function of `H2o` package in R for regression.

Consider I am using the name "aml" for building models.

```
aml <- h2o.automl(x=x, y=y, training_frame = train_set,
              max_models = 20, seed = 1,
              keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE)
```

The leaderboard of `automl()` shows the top performed models. I am able to print the importance of the predictors through h2o.varimp() function and plot a graph for the same using `h2o.varimp_plot()` function for only the leader model (the best model given by automl function).

```
h2o.varimp(aml@leader)
h2o.varimp_plot(aml@leader)
```

Is there any way to print the variable importance of the predictors for all the models in the leaderboard and plot a graph using the above two functions?

Comment: Please make your question more reproducible by providing code before this. That is, what exactly is  x? You can use `dput` for sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stacked Ensembles (usually the leader model) does not yet support variable importance (JIRA [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5137)).  However the variable importance for rest of the models can be retrieved in a loop over the model ids in the leaderboard.  See R code below.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# Import a sample binary outcome train/test set into H2O
train <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")

# Identify predictors and response
y <- "response"
x <- setdiff(names(train), y)

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[,y] <- as.factor(train[,y])

# Run AutoML for 10 models
aml <- h2o.automl(x = x, y = y,
                  training_frame = train,
                  max_models = 10,
                  seed = 1)

# View the AutoML Leaderboard
lb <- aml@leaderboard
print(lb, n = nrow(lb))

# Get model ids for all models in the AutoML Leaderboard
model_ids <- as.data.frame(lb$model_id)[,1]

# View variable importance for all the models (besides Stacked Ensemble)
for (model_id in model_ids) {
  print(model_id)
  m <- h2o.getModel(model_id)
  h2o.varimp(m)
  h2o.varimp_plot(m)
}
```